# PyCharm log without lose focus in IDE

Tags: pycharm

I'm logging my processing via the logging module in my code. This works fine, but everytime a log appears in the PyCharm run console, I lose focus from the editor. My code runs about 15min with continues logging. In this time can't work in the editor because the focus is always lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution...

You have to got to the **Run/Debug Configurations**, select your config and go to **Logs** and deactivate **Show console when a message is printed to standard error stream**.

If i use the default configuration from the logging module, this:

```
_log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

will always go to std.err.

Because it is missing somehow in the offical documentation, here the original implementation for the default StreamHandler:

```
class StreamHandler(Handler):
"""
A handler class which writes logging records, appropriately formatted,
to a stream. Note that this class does not close the stream, as
sys.stdout or sys.stderr may be used.
"""

terminator = '\n'

def __init__(self, stream=None):
    """
    Initialize the handler.

    If stream is not specified, sys.stderr is used.
    """
    Handler.__init__(self)
    if stream is None:
        stream = sys.stderr
    self.stream = stream
```